# Sentence construction

Tags: relative-pronouns, adverbial-phrases

1.He's like a viper, he strikes when **people aren't expecting**.

2.He's like a viper, he strikes when **people don't expect it**.

3.He's like a viper, he strikes when **people are least expecting it**.

4.He's like a viper, he strikes when **people least expect it**.

Are all the above sentences grammatically correct?
What's the difference in their meaning?
Would be alright to use any of them?

Comment: I'd go with option 4a as the most idiomatic:  "He's like a viper, he strikes when you least expect it."

Answer (score 1):

> 1.He's like a viper, he strikes when people aren't expecting.

This would seem like it is either missing a piece or using another idiom. "People are expecting" could be taken as [someone being pregnant](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/expecting) and so this may be misunderstood which while it is unlikely, it could happen that someone, perhaps like Sheldon from the Big Bang Theory if you want a specific reference to a nerd that may well make logical inferences that to others doesn't make sense happen.

> 2.He's like a viper, he strikes when people don't expect it.

This would be typical use and would be more normal in a sense.

> 3.He's like a viper, he strikes when people are least expecting it.

This seems a bit clunky though quite possibly correct I doubt I have heard it this way.

> 4.He's like a viper, he strikes when people least expect it.

This would have the most impact as the phrase at the end carries some weight in terms of implying a contrarian view.

Comment: No native speaker would infer any connection to pregnancy in OP's context.

Comment: Try Sheldon from the Big Bang Theory as an example of a native speaker where his eccentricities would make this a possibility to my mind. Never underestimate how some nerds and geeks may make bad guesses using cold logic.

Comment: But the Big Bang Theory is a *comedy!* Not that I watch it, but I doubt it's very intellectually challenging. And if a character on that show makes a dumb misinterpretation like that, you can bet the scriptwriters didn't do this by accident - *and* that they take it for granted their target audience will understand the "correct" interpretation for the context (they'll be laughing precisely *because* they're seeing someone do something stupid).

Comment: The point being that the "No native speaker" isn't quite right as I'm a native speaker and I made the post thus it can happen. It will be quite rare, yes. However, I'd argue the point of a non-zero probability here which you seem to highly disagree that I can find amusing in a way.

Comment: This site is primarily here for *learners*. Okay - English has many words that have many different meanings, but realistically I see no advantage in pointing out an alternative meaning that has no relevance to the one under consideration. Particularly when you do it in such a way that a learner might be misled into thinking he needs to be really careful in case people misunderstand the sense intended (which I maintain couldn't *possibly* happen here). It would be more credible (but still pointless) to contrast the *anticipate/require [as a matter of duty]* senses of the verb.